# What are the "User Mode" tools in kubernetes lens?

Tags: kubernetes

I have been using kuberentes lense and noticed under the cluster settings page an optional package called "user mode".  Does anybody know what this means?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it, but the description in your image is understandable. It is adding RBAC (user permission) so that any user (also non-admins) can *list namespaces* (e.g. see all namespaces that exists within the cluster).

But it should not mean more than that, e.g. a user can not create a Deployment in a namespace he is not granted to.